# avconv on Ubuntu 14.04 to convert .mp4 to .h264 with as is configuration

Tags: ubuntu, video, avconv

I am trying to use `avconv` on Ubuntu 14.04 to convert a .mp4 stream (which I am sure is intra coded) to .h264 (raw compressed stream). What are the options I should be using in avconv to ensure that I get the .h264 in exactly the same configuration as the .mp4 file.

`avconv -i DJI_0028.mp4 DJI_0028.h264`

When I do the above it seem to take a long time to get the raw stream out of the container mp4. This I think changes the encoding configuration of the file.

Additionally how is it possible to check all the encoding options (number of I frame, P frames etc) for a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If avconv has the same syntax as ffmpeg, use

```
avconv -i DJI_0028.mp4 -c copy -f h264 DJI_0028.h264
```